# How to update ListView in case of CursorAdapter usage?

Tags: android, listview

The reason I'm asking that is because `requery()` is deprecated. What is the best way now to refresh your `ListView`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`requery()` updates a `Cursor`, not a `CursorAdapter`.  As you say, it has been deprecated, and its replacement is:

```
oldCursor = myCursorAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor); // hands you back oldCursor
```

or:

```
myCursorAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor); // automatically closes old Cursor
```

`myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` notifies the `ListView` that the data set has changed, and it should refresh itself

Comment: Is it always necessary to call notifyDataSetChanged() in onLoadFinished and onLoaderReset?

Comment: I've seen a piece of code that doesn't use notifyDataSetChanged for a SimpleCursorAdapter and a ListView. If possible, do explain when notifyDataSetChanged needs to be called and why my example case doesn't need it.

Comment: There is no need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on CursorAdapter after either `changeCursor()` or `swapCursor()` calls - both methods call this method themselves, therefore your call will become just an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new cursor and call `changeCursor()` (documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29)) on your `CursorAdapter` instance or call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)) on your adapter.

Comment: I think your answer is misleading - changeCursor and notifyDataSetChanged are not interchangable, they do different jobs.

Comment: True and one should consider which is best for the given situation, but both will "refresh" the list view.

Comment: So they don't need to be called together?  Just calling one cancels out the need for calling the other?

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me, im not sure its the best way.

```
c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM mytable", null); //same line of the first initialization
adapter.swapCursor(c);
```

I refresh the only cursor, I dont know what to do with a new one.
Also i dont know pepole that answer with only a name of a function.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me, was to initialise new cursor, similar as previous one like:

```
cursor = dbHelper.myDataBase.rawQuery(StaticValues.SQL_CAT, null);

newCursor = dbHelper.myDataBase.rawQuery(StaticValues.SQL_CAT, null);
```

and then call:

```
adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
```

that updated my listview.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add my response as a comment but failed for some reason.

cursoradapter.notifyDatasetchanged() should not work as your adapter is linked to a "cursor" which holds a "query" that was executed before dataset was changed. Hence one would require to change "cursor" by doing the "new query" and link to cursoradapter using cursoradapter changecursor().