# Only one row is displayed in ListView: Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to create an activity wherein I have added a search facility to search contacts in the phonebook and list the selected contacts in a ListView.
I have been able to get one row of the ListView working. However, when I try to add another contact, it just replaces the first row. I am new to android app development. Unable to figure out how to get the desired output.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.SearchableInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FamilyAndFriends extends AppCompatActivity {

    Typeface mytypeface1;
    SearchView searchView;
    ListView contactlist;
    View contact_listview;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Cursor nameCursor;
    CursorAdapter nameAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_family_and_friends);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        mytypeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Light.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(mytypeface1);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Friends & Family");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        setupSearchView();

        layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        contactlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_info, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                break;
            case R.id.next:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
        searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    private String getDisplayContactName(Intent intent) {

        nameCursor = getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
        nameCursor.moveToFirst();
        int idDisplayName = nameCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        return nameCursor.getString(idDisplayName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (ContactsContract.Intents.SEARCH_SUGGESTION_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            final String CONTACT_NAME = getDisplayContactName(intent);
            nameAdapter = new CursorAdapter(this, nameCursor, false) {
                @Override
                public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                    contact_listview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_listview, parent, false);
                    return contact_listview;
                }

                @Override
                public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                    final TextView name_Contact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
                    name_Contact.setText(CONTACT_NAME);
                    name_Contact.setTypeface(mytypeface1);

                }
            };
        }
        contactlist.setAdapter(nameAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (nameCursor != null) {
            nameCursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any helps???

Comment: Hi there, have you tried instead of setting a new adapter updating the current using: `contactlist.getAdapter().swapCursor(nameAdapter);` because the issue seems to be that you are creating a fresh new cursor every time you add a new name.

Comment: where shall I add that line of code?? @azetaguionbajo

Comment: Sorry, replace this line: `contactlist.setAdapter(nameAdapter);` with this line `contactlist.getAdapter().swapCursor(nameAdapter);`

Comment: I tried doing that but it says 'Cannot resolve method 'swapCursor(android.widget.CursorAdapter)'

Comment: You're right, swapCursor needs a `Cursor` and not a `CursorAdapter`. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7026861/2879783) is pointing in the right direction.

Comment: still unable to resolve it. @azetaguionbajo

Comment: Everytime you create a new row, you call new CursorAdapter and set it to your listview.. you should have an Array, add a new row, and use notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh

Comment: @RicardoBarroca can you please post code for doing that???

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it sounds like you are returning **only one item** in your `getItemCount()`

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
```

you need to return the size of the list that you are passing in your adapter

Comment: how shall I override this method?? I am not extending any adapter class.

Comment: you have to, when you extend the array adapter or base adapter you need to overide that method

Comment: Can I do it without extending any adapter class??. if yes, then how?? plz guide. @war_Hero